# How do I convert an enum to a list and replace '_' with ' ' (space)

Tags: c#, enums

I have a enum as:-

```
    public enum EnumType
    {
        Type1_Template,
        Type2_Folders,
        Type3_Template,
        Type1_Folders,
    }
```

Now, in my Controller i want

1. List of Enum and
2. Replace the _ underscores with space.

So for that :-
Getting List of Enum i have

```
return new Models.DTOObject()
            {
                ID = model.id,
                Name = model.Name,
                Description = model.Description,
                //Type is the property where i want the List<Enum> and replace the underscore with space
                Type = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumType)).Cast<EnumType>().ToList()
            };
```

But now, i am trying something like this (may sound weird though ):-

```
return new Models.Customers()
            {
                ID = model.id,
                Name = model.Name,
                Description = model.Description,
                //Type is the property where i want the List<Enum> and replace the underscore with space
                Type = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumType)).Cast<EnumType>().ToList().Select(e => new
                {
                    Value = e,
                    Text = e.ToString().Replace("_", " ")
                })
            };
```

but throws syntax errors(';' missing ). Though it was just hit an try kind of stuff. Please let me know how can i achieve it.

Comment: "but throws syntax errors" isn't a clear description of what's wrong. *What* errors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to just do

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(EnumType)).Select(item => item.Replace('_',' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
string[] names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(EnumType));
```

Afterwards you can use a for-loop (or something similar) and replace "_" with " ".

```
for(int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++){
   names[i].Replace('_',' ');
}
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx);

Comment: Any reason you particular want to avoid LINQ here?